# exporting/using express-session in another file

Tags: node.js, express, session

What's the best/common way to use an express-session in other files? I have  trouble integrating the session into my code. I was using auth tokens, but I would like to use sessions instead. 
I defined session in my `server.js`:

```
const express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

var app = express();
app.use(cookieParser('secret'));
app.use(session({
    key: 'user_sid',
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        expires: 600000
    }
}));

// stuff

module.exports = {app, session};
```

And it works fine! But When I try to use it in my `userController.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var {session} = require('./../server');

module.exports.login = (req, res) => {
  var body = _.pick(req.body, ['email', 'password']);
  User.findByEmailAndPassword(body.email, body.password).then((user) => {
    // console.log(req.session); // is undefined
    res.render('dashboard.hbs');
  }).catch((e) => {
    res.status(400).send();
  });
}
```

then `req.session` is `undefined`. 
I know what I'm doing isn't right, obviously, but what's the right way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have to export `session` at all, as you are telling your `app` to use it in `server.js`.

So the working fiddle should be looking like the following:

```js
const express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

var app = express();
app.use(cookieParser('secret'));
app.use(session({
  key: 'user_sid',
  secret: 'secret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    expires: 600000
  }
}));

// stuff

module.exports = app;
```

and your controller:

```js
module.exports.login = (req, res) => {
  var body = _.pick(req.body, ['email', 'password']);
  User.findByEmailAndPassword(body.email, body.password).then((user) => {
    // console.log(req.session); // is undefined
    res.render('dashboard.hbs');
  }).catch((e) => {
    res.status(400).send();
  });
}
```

I am considering that you are going to use this exported login function for a route, like

`app.use('/login', require('yourCtrl.js').login);`

Comment: Yes, the function is used in `routes/users.js` (`router.post('/users/login', userController.login);`) - I just don't quite understand, if it should be working the way it is, why is `req.session` undefined when I try to log it?

Comment: please create a fiddle